# Is it possible to update two different models with single action button in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

My question is i have defined one function & one action button to update same data in different model.

But I want it to update some fields in two different models.
individual codes are working fine but when i merge them its showing error.

My code is like this.

```
def function_call(self,cr,uid,ids,vals,context=None):   
       x = self.pool.get('hotel.booking')
       y = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
       z = {  
       'name' : y.name,
       'mobile':y.mobile,
       'email_id':y.email_id
        }
       return x.create(cr,uid,z,context=context)    

objz1 = self.pool.get('room.engage')    
currentz1 = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
currentz1.status = 'reserved' 
new_valsz1 = {  #dictionary
    'room_num' : currentz1.room_num.room_num,
    'room_type':currentz1.room_type,
    'status': currentz1.status
    }
return objz1.create(cr,uid,new_valsz1,context=context)
```

Action button is in booking form.. where customer enters name, mobile, email_id, room number details.

In the above code it works only if i remove one segment.
So from this i want to get personal details in one model, room details in another model.

Comment: post the error that you faced.

Comment: i am not getting anything .. simply it taking room details to engaged rooms model.. but i want some personal details to booking data model tooo... Thanks

Comment: why there is return statement after filling up the 'hotel.booking' record creation? If you want to enter the data in other model also then you should remove that first 'return' statement. And I am not sure but you are missing the indentation for the block of code for 'room.engage'

Comment: Hey its working.. nothing wrong with my code.. but we have to remove 1st return statement give at the bottom. DOne..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem.
you must have ids for each model to browse records and call create method twice.
(when you write return obj.create(cr, uid, vals, context), you return the id of the new created record.)